# Outlook.RecurrencePattern to iCal string

Tags: icalendar, recurrence

Is there an easy way to convert an Outlook.Recurrence object to a recurrence string in iCal format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is helpful - but http://sourceforge.net/projects/dday-ical/ is what most people reference when creating iCal feed/string/etc.